# validate variable before use in function

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, int, signature, webmethod

I have a c# function with this signature:

```
public XmlNode getName(int a, double b){}
```

problem is that the a variable is not always a valid int (the user can leave it null or a space. In these cases, the function fails (not surprising). How can I validate the int being an int before\in the start of the function?

---

EDIT:

the function is a WEBMETHOD in a webservice (asmx file) and that is why the user can type any value into a. The problem is that the webservice crashes when somebody enters a string instead of an int and that is what i want to avoid.

Comment: if `a` is not int you can't call that function, what do you mean with 'validation'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way a user is passing space or null to that function. You are. You gave it a signature of int, it won't compile if you try to call it with something that coul dbe null or space.

If you mean the input you are passing to it is a string but it's only valid for int then. What do you want to with those two inputs. Perhaps it's return null. Donlt blame me if it isn't..

```
public XmlNode getName(String a, double b)
{
   int someval;
   if (int.TryParse(s, out someval))
   {
       // do whatever you were going to in here, but using someval not a
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you need to pass a valid int to your method. You can't for example call it like this:

```
getName("", 3);
```

This will give you a compile error because the first argument is not of type `int`.

So you have two options:

1. Let the callers convert the user input to an `int`.
2. Adjust your method signature to accept a type of `string`, `object` or `Nullable<int>`.

`Nullable<int>` allows callers of your method to pass `null`. You can use `a.HasValue` to check if the user passed `null` or a valid `int`. ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx))

For converting values in the .NET Framework you have three other options:

[int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

This method takes a string parameter and tries to convert it to an `int`. If the conversion fails or if the `string` is `null`, an exception is thrown.

[int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

This method takes a `string` and an output paramater and tries the conversion. If it fails, no exception is thrown. Instead the method returns falls and you can decide what to do.

[Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx)

This method takes an argument of type object. It doesn't throw on a null but returns the default value (for int this is 0). Other then that it uses int.Parse internally.

In your case you can do something like:

```
public XmlNode getName(string a, double b)
{
   if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
   {
      // Handle null case
   }

   int result;
   if (!int.TryParse(a, out result)
   {
     // handle invalid int case
   }

   // Use result to get your XmlNode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try to parse the user input into an `int`. If it fails, don't call the `getName` function.

```
            var isAInt = "1";
            var isNotAnInt = "f";
            String nothing = null;
            int tmp;
            var res1 = Int32.TryParse(isAInt, out tmp); // true
            var res2 = Int32.TryParse(isNotAnInt, out tmp); // false
            var res3 = Int32.TryParse(nothing, out tmp); // false
```